# Is A Mocking Library Redundant If I Already Have a Stub?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, data-access-layer

Let's say I have the following classes in the respective source folders/packages...

```
[src/myApp]
|_Employee «concrete»
|_Manager «abstract» 
|_ManagerImpl «concrete» (Class Under Test)
|_Recruiter «abstract» 
|_RecruiterImpl «concrete» (Collaborator)
```

...

```
public class ManagerImpl implements Manager {
   ...
   private Recruiter recR;
   ...

   public void growTeam( Object criteria ){ 
      //...check preconditions
      Employee newB = recR.srcEmployee( criteria );
      //...whatever else
   }

   ...

}
```

...

```
[test/myApp]
|_RecruiterStandIn «concrete»
|_ManagerImplTest
```

...

```
public class RecruiterStandIn implements Recruiter { 

   Map<Object, Employee> reSrcPool = new HashMap<>();

   public RecruiterStandIn( ){ 
      // populate reSrcPool with dummy test data...
   }    

   public Employee srcEmployee( Object criteria ){
      return reSrcPool.get( criteria );
   }
}
```

...

```
public class ManagerImplTest {
   ...
   // Class Under Test
   private ManagerImpl mgr;

   // Collaborator
   private Recruiter recR = new RecruiterStandIn( );
   ...

   public void testGrowTeam(  ) {
      //...
      mgr.setRecruiter( recR ); 
      mgr.growTeam( criteria );
      // assertions follow...
   }

   ...    
}
```

...

***Here are my questions***: Given that I have a `RecruiterStandIn` concrete implementation that already exists within the codebase for testing purposes (*in the `test` scope*)...

1. ***Would it be redundant to also use a mock in the above unit test?***
2. ***What would be the value (if any)*** in *additionally* ***doing something like this in the above unit test?***

...

```
...
@Mock
private Recruiter recR;
...

...
public void testGrowTeam(  ) { 
   ...
   expect( recR.srcEmployee( blah) ).andReturn( blah )...
   // exercising/assertions/validations as usual...
}
...
```

You can safely assume that `RecruiterStandIn` does everything the class under test will ever require of it for the purposes of the above unit test. That is to say, for the sake of simple answers/explanations, there's no need to overcomplicate the above scenario with contrived *what-ifs* around maintenance of the stub and whatnot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answers to your specific questions:

1. **Would it be redundant to also use a mock in the above unit test?**

As the unit test is written right now it would be redundant but my see answer to your second question below.

2. **What would be the value (if any) in additionally doing something like this in the above unit test?**

It think this is the way you should be doing your tests and I would recommend getting rid of your stub, `RecruiterStandIn`. Instead I would setup the recruit to return canned answers so you don't have to maintain two classes just to return some predefined data:

```
@Spy
private Recruiter recR;

public void testGrowTeam(  ) { 

     // Setup canned data return
     doReturn(generateTestEmployee()).when(recR).srcEmployee(any(Object.class));

    expect( recR.srcEmployee( blah) ).andReturn( blah )...
    // exercising/assertions/validations as usual...
}
```

FYI the above syntax would be for using Mockito. From what I can tell in your case Mockito gives you the power of stubbing out certain parts and much more without requiring you to create new test entities.

**Original Answer**

Definitely yes you should be doing mock object tests. [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).  Mock object testing allows you to test the interactions between your classes and ensure that things are interacting with the world around them correctly. I think there is less value in these tests when you first write the classes and their corresponding tests. Mock object tests shine a year down the road when a new developer comes in and inadvertently your breaks code because she didn't understand that certain internal behavior was needed..

A somewhat contrived example would be if let's say we had a Car that needed to fill up some gas:

```
public class Car {
      public void fuelUp()
}
```

Now with standard unit tests we would check that after calling `fuelUp()` the car was full of gas and that the proper amount of money was deducted from the driver. But since we never tested how `fuelUp()` was interacting with the world around it, it could easily be doing the following:

```
public void fueldUp() {
    siphonGasFromNearestCar();
    buyCoffeeAndChips()
}
```

But with mock object testing you can ensure that the Car is getting filled up in the proper and expected way.

Comment: Thanks tkeE2036. I'm already sold on mocks. But thanks for the evangelism just the same. I'd still appreciate an answer to the crux of my questions — which I think you've overlooked.

Comment: If you found my post helpful please consider accepting it to help others in the future :)

Comment: At the risk of sounding ungrateful, if my question was, "Should I be doing mock object tests?" Then you'd be right on the money. If my focus was concerned with some time "down the road", then you'd be batting a thousand. As it is, however, my focus right now is only the ***above*** example. I'm specifically asking  whether or not using a mock would be redundant — given the ***above*** example. Only.

Comment: As I said in my post, as written right now it would be redundant. I went onto say that I would get rid of your stub and use a framework to create your stub instead even if you never want to do mock testing.

Comment: Thx tkeE2036. Awesome follow-up! I read your answer to Q2, as, "*the value is, you don't have to maintain two classes just to return some predefined data*". Right? But to which "*two classes*" are you referring? `Recruiter` MUST stay. `Employee` MUST stay. I can see losing one class (`RecruiterStandIn`). But which other one are you counting as your second one to lose?

Comment: I meant having to maintain both `RecruiterImpl` and `RecruiterStandIn`. Since `RecruiterStandIn` implements `Recruiter` any additional methods you add to `Recruiter` will have to be implemented in both `RecruiterImpl` and `RecruiterStandIn`